# Passing Arguments to function in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017, ecma

I have a function(case) as below,

```
let fn = (() => {
  let ab = {}; 
  let register = () => {
    console.log("hello" + ab[x])
  };
  return (x,y) => {
    ab[x] = y;
    return register();
  };
})();
```

this function is working only when I call as below,

```
let x = 'key';
let y = 'value';
fn(x,y);
```

Is there any chance to call directly like

```
fn('key', 'value');
```

what changes I have to make in function to call directly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `register` function doesn't know about `x`. You need to pass it through from your previous function:

```js
let fn = (() => {
  let ab = {}; 
  let register = (x) => {
    console.log("hello" + ab[x])
  };
  return (x,y) => {
    ab[x] = y;
    return register(x);
  };
})();

fn("key", "value");
```

Comment: I used other way:
`
let fn = (() => {
  let ab = {}; 
  let register = () => {
   for(let key in ab){
  console.log("hello"+ab[key]);
   }
 };
   return (x,y) => {
      ab[x]=y;
      return register();
    };
})();
`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you aren’t defining the parameters in the functions.

```
   let fn = ((x,y) => {
  let ab = {}; 
  let register = () => {
    console.log("hello"+ab[x])};
    return (x,y) => {
      ab[x]=y;
      return register();
    };
})();
```